# Unable to deserialize Kafka stream to pojo. Could not find class specified in writer's schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

> Getting exception while reading from kafka topic: Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   deserializing Avro message for id 1 Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find
>   class USERS specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's
>   schema for a SpecificRecord.

I think deserialising is not correct and i am not able to find any proper example also.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG , "TEST");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");

    props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
                    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,SpecificAvroSerde.class);

                    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
                    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();




    KStream<String,USERS> valid = builder.stream("testUSERS");

valid.foreach((k,v)-> System.out.println("v ="+v.getUSERNAME()));
valid.foreach((k,v)-> System.out.println("k ="+k));

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(),props);

streams.cleanUp();

streams.start();
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using kafka's configuration to require a specific schema in this case the consumed schema must exist in your class path so that it is possible to parse it, if not, configure to use GenericRecord

```
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false);
```

Comment: I face the same issue, what's the solution if we use a remote schema registry?

Comment: same solution being remote does not change the way lib will handle the serialization of avros.